# How is the entropy of uniformly distributed probability mass functions distributed?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, entropy

This question is quite similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2266285/expected-entropy-based-on-dirichlet-distribution) but not exactly the same.

Suppose we have a random vector $P \in R^n$ with $\|P\|_1 = 1$, which represents a probability mass function over a finite set of outcomes $X = \{X_1, ..., X_n\}$. This vector is distributed according to a flat Dirichlet distribution with parameters $\alpha_i = 1$: $$P \sim Dirichlet(n, \alpha = (1, ..., 1))$$ or equivalently $$P_i \sim Beta(1, n - 1)$$ which is a uniform distribution of points over the $(n-1)$-simplex.

Given one of these $p$'s, we can calculate its entropy $$H(p) = E_p[-\log_n(p)] = \Sigma_{i=1}^n -p_i\log_n(p_i) \in [0, 1].$$ My question is, what would be the associated distribution of the value of $H(P)$?

I am not sure whether it is possible to go step-by-step in order to how to find the distribution of $-P_i \log_n(P_i)$ and then the sum over all $i$ (as they are correlated). I've noticed that from the distribution of $P_i$ we know that $-\log(1 - P_i)$ is distributed as $Exponential(n - 1)$, that might be useful. The other way around has me trying to get something out of $H(P) = E_P[-\log_n(P)]$, where the expected value itself is a random variable, but whether this makes sense at all is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer / too long for a comment

I am not an expert on Dirichlet distribution, so please let me start with a question: If we condition on the last $p_n = 1- \lambda$, and re-scale the rest via

$$q_i = {p_i \over \lambda} \,\,\,\,\,\,\forall i \in {1,2,\dots, n-1}$$

so that $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} q_i = 1$, would the $q_i$ be distributed according to $Dirichlet(n-1, (1,1,\dots,1))$, and be independent of $p_n$?  Intuitively this seems it should be true, based on the description of Dirichlet as uniform on vectors with $||p||_1 = 1$, but hopefully someone more knowledgeable can confirm this.

Anyway, if the above is true, then maybe induction on $n$ would be a viable approach?  This is inspired by the OP's "step by step" comment, and working out some details.

$$
\begin{array}{}
H_{n-1}(q) &= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} -q_i \log q_i \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} - {p_i \over \lambda} \log {p_i \over \lambda} \\
&= {1 \over \lambda} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} -p_i (\log p_i - \log \lambda)\\
&= {1 \over \lambda} (\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (-p_i \log p_i) + \log \lambda \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} p_i)\\
&= {1 \over \lambda} (H_n(p) + p_n \log p_n + \log \lambda (1-p_n))\\
&= {1 \over 1 - p_n} (H_n(p) + p_n \log p_n + 2 \log (1-p_n))
\\
H_n(p) &= (1 - p_n) H_{n-1}(q) - p_n \log p_n - 2 \log (1-p_n)
\end{array}
$$

So assuming independence, we know the distribution of $p_n$, and by induction the distribution of $H_{n-1}(q)$, the last equation shows how to combine these two random variables into a new r.v. $H_n(p)$.  And as the OP suspected, it does not seem to be as simple as "summing all $-p_i \log p_i$".  The combination above seems very complicated though, so I am not sure there is a good way to proceed (unless you are just interested in simple stuff like $E[H(p)]$).

Anyway, hope this is somewhat helpful.