# Meaning of a particular integral on the space of probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Motivated by some possible interpretation of some problem in physics,  I have the following integral:

Let $X= X_1..X_n$ be a set of fixed real numbers.

The integral is  : $I(X) = \int Dp\exp (- V_p(X))  $,

where $Dp = dp_1..dp_n  \delta( \sum^n_{i=1}p_i-1)  $, here the $ p_i$ are  probabilities, real positive quantities in the interval $[0,1]$.

and $ V_p(X) $ is the variance of $ X$, relatively to the probability law $p$, that is: $  V_p(X) =   \sum^n_{i=1}p_i X_i^2 -   (  \sum^n_{i=1}p_iX_i )^2 $

I am interested, not mainly by the precise value of the quantity $  I(X)$,  but more by its hypothetical meaning in some maths realm.

So, in maths, does $I(X)$ mean something, or/and
 is it useful for something , or/and is there something resembling ?

Comment: the Dirac delta function $Dp$ with constraint that all probabilities sum to 1 makes me think the integral represents the gamut of various probabilities across the $n$ variables $\{ X \}$

Comment: does $I$ represent a partition function of sorts ....

Comment: in what context did this arise

Comment: @phdmba7of12 The original context has nothing to do with probabilities...it is in some context of scattering amplitudes.

Comment: I think what you have here is the flat version of the [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) over $\vec{p}$ and you are evalulating $E[exp(-Var(\vec{p}))]$.  Sorry this doesn't really answer your question of what it means...  but perhaps some more googling would uncover something?

Comment: [This thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2266285/expected-entropy-based-on-dirichlet-distribution) deals with the expected _entropy_ $E[H(\vec{p})]$ for the flat Dirichlet distribution.  It is pretty normal to study the entropy of a distribution, or the variance of a distribution, but this is the first time I have seen a question asked about the $e^{-Var}$ of a distribution.

Comment: @antkam Thank you very much for the information and your efforts